# difference between sizeof(foo) and sizeof(foo()) in C

Tags: c

What is the difference between `sizeof(foo)` and `sizeof(foo())` where foo is any simple function.
In gcc (4.7.2)
I am getting `sizeof(fun) = 1` and `sizeof(fun()) = 4`. 
Earlier I perceived that foo is stored as a pointer in symbol table. Can someone explain why I am getting 1 in first case and 4 in other ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(){
int a=1,b=4,x=5;
printf("hi\n");
}

int main(){
printf("%d",sizeof(fun()));
}
```

Comment: and it doesn't actually call `fun()`.

Comment: `sizeof(fun())` is easy to understand. Why is `sizeof(fun)==1`?

Comment: that's right, I understand fun() has to be resolved as int and return 4 with sizeof , but my question was , why sizeof(fun) = 1 ?

Comment: The deleted answer of @GrijeshChauhan is correct.  `sizeof(fun)` shouldn't compile at all.

Comment: The MS compiler rejects it! A rare victory for it!!

Comment: http://ideone.com/svhQPv ..it is giving answer 4 in case of sizeof(fun()) and compilation error in case of sizeof(fun) http://ideone.com/RRoOyj

Comment: @KamleshArya Yes, and it is obvious why that is so

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan..thats what i am confused with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, looks like gcc choose to ignore the standards , because this compiles fine with gcc. Must be to support some other thing

Comment: @SushantChoudhary Most likely it is just a bug.

Comment: @David yes, I am also thinking the same , or may be constraint violation as the duplicate post you said is pointing to